# Using view or trigger to preprocess data

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with the following structure and data, representing the states of a parking bay:

```
id  bayID   state     starttime
1   1       FREE      2013-08-09 09:13:02
2   1       OCCUPIED  2013-08-09 09:15:50
3   1       FREE      2013-08-09 09:33:15
4   1       OCCUPIED  2013-08-09 09:35:10
5   1       FREE      2013-08-09 10:03:22
```

I now need to calculate average parking occupancy times for a bay. Since the records can be in the millions, I'm looking for the optimal way to do this, so that querying the averages can be done fast.

My idea was to preprocess the data from the table above into another table where the parking time has already been calculated. This would be done by finding a pair of OCCUPIED and FREE entries for a bay and then calculate the time differences between the starting times. This could give me a structure like this:

```
bayID   starttime             duration
1       2013-08-09 09:15:50   ...
1       2013-08-09 09:35:10   ...
```

I could then query between 2 datetimes and average out the duration.

If this seems like the recommended approach, I was wondering how the calculated dataset would be created. I guess I could:

- create **a trigger** that executes after an insert in the first table, does the calculation and inserts in another table if needed.
- create **a view** on the first table. I don't have enough MySQL knowledge to know if this is possible unfortunately.

Before I dive into coding, could anyone give me some advice on the proposed solutions? Are they both feasible and what would be the (dis)advantages of using one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for advices, so here are my two cents...

> Are they both feasible

MySQL support both triggers and views. So technically speaking both solution are feasible.

> - create a **trigger** that executes after an insert in the first table, does the calculation and inserts in another table if needed.
> - create a **view** on the first table. I don't have enough MySQL knowledge to know if this is possible unfortunately.

Using a **trigger** seems to be an interesting approach at first since that will give you a live update of your occupation table. But this will increase the *average* load on your DB, maybe up to an unacceptable point if it is fired often. On the "good side", the query in the trigger would probably be more lightweight that with your other solution.

MySQL support **views**, but you have to remember that those are static snapshot made at view-creation time. There no such things as "live views" in MySQL. That implies that you will need to *re-create* that view on periodic basis (cronjob?). Say once every night? Depending on your needs, that latency might or might not be acceptable. In addition, since you said you have millions of records, probably the nightly consolidation of data might put an important load on the DB *at that time*. If you running a 24/7 application, this might be unacceptable.

As a rough conclusion, both solutions have pros and cons, and I would say there is no clear winner considering the description you gave of the system. Maybe someone could come with a third solution more appropriate...

Hope this helps at least a little ;)

---